# make a helper for my methods for integration testing in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, integration-testing

I'm preparing some integration tests on my rails 3.2.16 application, I figured that, in my user scenarios, I have several calls that I repeat over many tests, so I would like to DRY them up, by placing them in a separate common module,

for example I have created `/test/integration/my_test_helpers.rb`:

```
require 'test_helper'

module MyTestHelper

  def login_user(email, password, stay = 0)
    login_data = {
      email: email,
      password: password,
      remember_me: stay
    }
    post "/users/sign_in", user: login_data
    assert_redirected_to :user_root
  end
end
```

and tried to use it in my integration test:

```
require 'test_helper'
require "./my_test_helpers.rb"

class CreateCommentTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  setup do
    @user = users(:user1)
  end

  test "create comment" do
    login_user @user.email, "password", 1
  end
end
```

I get exception:

```
`require': cannot load such file -- ./my_test_helpers.rb (LoadError)
```

How can I load the module? is it right to make `MyTestHelpers` a module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put your helper in support folder(`test/support/my_test_helpers.rb`, or something) and load module in `test_helper.rb`:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= "test"
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require "rails/test_help"

require_relative "./support/my_test_helpers"

require "minitest/rails"

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending!

  fixtures :all

  # Add more helper methods to be used by all tests here...
end
```

Do not remember `include` your module:

```
require 'test_helper'

class CreateCommentTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  include MyTestHelper

  setup do
    @user = users(:user1)
  end

  test "create comment" do
    login_user @user.email, "password", 1
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you, that's much better now, though I have still a `undefined method `login_user'`